# Clustering with adjacency matrix - r

Tags: r

I have an adjacency matrix of the type :

```
IDvariant   Amp-Lib1-100913_L1308034_IonXpress-10_TMAP.vcf      Amp-Lib1-100913_L1308034_IonXpress-10_TMAP_2.vcf    Amp-Lib1-100913_L1308034_IonXpress-10_TMAP_3.vcf

3496    1   1   0

3497    1   1   0

3498    1   1   0

3501    0   1   0

3502    0   1   0

...
```

with sample names in column names, variant ID in row names and 1 if the sample has the variant and 0 otherwise.

I would like to calculate a distance from this matrix and draw a "cluster tree" and a heatmap with R.

I proceed as follows:

```
require(vegan)
data=read.table('adjacency_matrix.txt', header=T, row.names=1)
dist=vegdist(data, method='jaccard')
fit=hclust(dist, method='average')
png(filename='cluster_tree.png')
plot(fit, main='Clustering with Jaccard distance')
dev.off()
```

and I get a crashed graph. I do not have the right to post a picture, otherwise I would have shown.

If someone can help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it work without the lines with `png` and `dev.off()` ?